# Fastest C# Code to Download a Web Page

Tags: c#

Given a URL, what would be the most efficient code to download the contents of that web page? I am only considering the HTML, not associated images, JS and CSS.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
public static void DownloadFile(string remoteFilename, string localFilename)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile(remoteFilename, localFilename);
}
```

Comment: This is the slowest!, instancing a new WebClient has  3-5 delay before it actually does the download i heard it's due to checking for proxy support. I would recommend using a Socket approach to download as thats the fastest possible solution

Comment: I interpreted fastest as "with as few letters of code as possible".

Comment: @SSpoke You don't have to use a new instance each time you download a site, you can use a static instance of Webclient to avoid the delay.

Answer (score 29):

[System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx)

From MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
        }
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        // Add a user agent header in case the 
        // requested URI contains a query.

        client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wish MSDN would actually dispose of IDisposable resources in their examples.  One little exception and the Stream/StreamReader will not be cleaned up.  `using` is your friend.

Answer (score 23):

Use the WebClient class from System.Net; on .NET 2.0 and higher.

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", " C:\myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 10):

[WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static void DownloadString (string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    string reply = client.DownloadString (address);

    Console.WriteLine (reply);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

here is my answer ,a method that takes a URL and return a string

```
public static string downloadWebPage(string theURL)
    {
        //### download a web page to a string
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead(theURL);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work with https sites.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the fastest (download speed time with low latency) solution for download.

```
// WebClient vs HttpClient vs HttpWebRequest vs RestSharp
// در نهایت به نظرم روش زیر سریعترین روشه
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
Request.Proxy = null;
Request.Method = "GET";
using (WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return Reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a fast and short method to download files from Internet. It uses the new HttpClient object, new to .NET Framework 4.0+ and can be used also with .NET. It also uses the aync await.

```
async Task<string> CurlAsync(string url) => await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

// usage:

var content = await CurlAsync(myURL);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.