# C#: How to read data from webbrowser in a windows application

Tags: c#, http

**First of all i am doing a Windows application. Not a web application.**

Now i am doing on application to send SMS (Short message) from System to Mobile.

Here, i am using a http URL to push the message having parameters To (number) and Msg (test message).

after forming the URL, like

http://333.33.33.33:3333/csms/PushURL.cgi?USERNAME=xxxx&PASSWORD=xxxx&MOBILENO=919962391144&MESSAGE=TestMessage&TYPE=0&CONTENT_TYPE=text;

Here i mentioned 3 for ip address, X for passwords and user id because of confidential.

After sending this URL, i am receiving some text like "Message Send Successfully", in the browser window.

Just i want to read the text and store in the database.

My problem is: how can i read the text from the web browser.

please held me!

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET , see [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) - 
Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

Seen here a few times, e.g. [fastest c# code to download a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233/fastest-c-code-to-download-a-web-page)

**EDIT**: the `System.Net.WebClient` class is not connected to web applications, and can be easily used in console or winforms applications. The C# example in the MSDN link is a standalone console app (compile and run it to check):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
    }
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();

    client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    Console.WriteLine (s);
    data.Close ();
    reader.Close ();
}
```

}

Comment: thanks gimel, i forgot to say one thing , i am developing a windows application, not a web application

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code from Microsoft's [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
        }
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        // Add a user agent header in case the 
        // requested URI contains a query.

        client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for all that stream nonsense, just use client.DownloadString

Comment: thanks gimel, i forgot to say one thing , i am developing a windows application, not a web application